# 2checkout unauthorized error Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, 2checkout

I'm trying to use Sandbox 2checkout API but I'm facing some issues. 
I am using Laravel as php framework and 2co.min.js to generate the token.
When I fill the inputs and press submit I got 'unauthorized'.

I get the seller id from my sandbox account and the public, private key 
for the API and checked them but I still get this error:

**The seller id , public and private keys**

[image: The seller id , public and private keys]

### The HTML CODE

```
    <form id="myCCForm" class="col-md-6" action="{{ route('pay') }}" method="post">
        @csrf
        <input id="token1" name="token1" type="hidden" value="">
        <div>
            <label>
                <span>Card Number</span>
            </label>
            <input id="ccNo" type="text" size="20" value="" autocomplete="off" required/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>
                <span>Expiration Date (MM/YYYY)</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" size="2" id="expMonth" required/>
            <span> / </span>
            <input type="text" size="2" id="expYear" required/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>
                <span>CVC</span>
            </label>
            <input id="cvv" size="4" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" required/>
            <input type="text" id="billingAddr" name="billingAddr" placeholder="Billing Adr ">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Payment">
    </form>
```

**The JS Code**

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/api/2co.min.js"></script>

<script>

// Pull in the public encryption key for our environment
// Called when token created successfully.
var successCallback = function (data) {
    var myTokenInput = document.getElementById('token1');

    // Set the token as the value for the token input
    myTokenInput.value = data.response.token.token;

    // IMPORTANT: Here we call `submit()` on the form element directly instead of using jQuery to prevent and infinite token request loop.
    myForm.submit();
};

// Called when token creation fails.
var errorCallback = function (data) {
    if (data.errorCode === 200) {
        console.log(data);
    } else {
        console.log(data);
    }
};

var tokenRequest = function () {
    // Setup token request arguments
    var args = {
        sellerId: "203840804",
        publishableKey: "ACC02BE7-70FC-4AEF-9F75-D592E299DEDA​",
        ccNo: $("#ccNo").val(),
        cvv: $("#cvv").val(),
        expMonth: $("#expMonth").val(),
        expYear: $("#expYear").val(),
        billingAddr: $("#billingAddr").val()
    };

    // Make the token request
    TCO.requestToken(successCallback, errorCallback, args);
};

$(function () {
    // Pull in the public encryption key for our environment
    TCO.loadPubKey('production');

    $("#myCCForm").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Call our token request function
        tokenRequest();

        // Prevent form from submitting
        return false;
    });
});
```

### I Need Help Guys

Comment: Try replacing TCO.loadPubKey('production'); with TCO.loadPubKey('sandbox');

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the senderId and the publishableKey in your script.

Change the tokenRequest function to this one:

```
var tokenRequest = function () {
    // Setup token request arguments
    var args = {
        sellerId: "901389630",
        publishableKey: "A4B8A470-61A2-470E-9DCB-013A033FD206",
        ccNo: $("#ccNo").val(),
        cvv: $("#cvv").val(),
        expMonth: $("#expMonth").val(),
        expYear: $("#expYear").val(),
        billingAddr: $("#billingAddr").val()
    };

    // Make the token request
    TCO.requestToken(successCallback, errorCallback, args);
};
```

And like @LahiruTM wrote, change the `TCO.loadPubKey('production');` to `TCO.loadPubKey('sandbox');`